# Extract url from javascript String

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the following `String` :

```
http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/AFP/a418cb581c41fd9c36b0d24c054ad4c623bab222.jpg
```

from this `String` :

```
https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/yqEp3ogcVvfSaDSSIq.Llg--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/AFP/a418cb581c41fd9c36b0d24c054ad4c623bab222.jpg
```

**And before, extract, i would like to check if the global String contains more than one time "http" to be sure to extract the jpg only when needed.**

How can i do that ?

Comment: You can easily do this using a regex. Use regexpal.com to create one and use it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the data like this:

```
var myStr = "https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/yqEp3ogcVvfSaDSSIq.Llg--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/AFP/a418cb581c41fd9c36b0d24c054ad4c623bab222.jpg"
var splittedStr = myStr.split("-");
var extractedStr = splittedStr[3].slice(1);
```

To find out how many "http" is present in the string:

```
var count = (myStr.match(/http/g)).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopes it helps

```
var source = "https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/yqEp3ogcVvfSaDSSIq.Llg--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/AFP/a418cb581c41fd9c36b0d24c054ad4c623bab222.jpg"
var temp = source.replace("https","http").split("http");
var result = 'http'+temp[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

use split()

```
var original = "https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/yqEp3ogcVvfSaDSSIq.Llg--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9NzU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/fr_FR/News/AFP/a418cb581c41fd9c36b0d24c054ad4c623bab222.jpg";
original = original.split('-/');
alert($(original)[original.length-1]);
```

your require URL shows in alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex :

```
str.match(/(http?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/i)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jXZm/)